# Graphics effects not available in 11.04 like in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, graphics, effects

I used to like the graphic effects in Maverick. but I cannot find a way to apply graphic effects in Natty unlike Maverick. Were the effects dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably referring to the lack of a `Desktop Effects` tab in `gnome-appearance-properties`.

You still can configure desktop effects using
 [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] in the same way, the only difference will be the fact that enabling Desktop Cube would require some [extra steps](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/compiz-cube-natty/).

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Another tip: In case something goes wrong with the Compiz settings, you can reset them by running this command:

```
unity --replace
```

Comment: dunno why, but something's wrong with that compizconfig-settings-manager link. It shows up perfectly in the answer preview, but here it comes up horribly.

Answer (score 0):

Use in **Terminal**

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

Now configure the settings